# Show multiple requirements js validation

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show all the validation messages when something is required.

So far I got this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<td>
<form name="form">
<tr>
Voornaam: <p><input type="text" name="voornaam"></p>
</tr>
<tr>
Achternaam: <p><input type="text" name="achternaam"></p>
</tr>
<tr>
Telefoonnummer: <p><input type="text" name="telefoon"></p>
</tr>
<tr>
Emailadres: <p><input type="text" name="email"></p>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Stuur op">
</tr>
</form>
</td>
</table>

<div id="berichten">

</div>
<script>
var validator = new FormValidator('form', [{
    name: 'voornaam',
    display: 'Voornaam',    
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'achternaam',
    display: 'achternaam', 
    rules: 'required'
},{
    name: 'telefoon',
    display: 'telefoon', 
    rules: 'numeric'
},{
    name: 'email',
    display: 'email', 
    rules: 'valid_email'
}], function(errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = (errors[i].message);   
        }

    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it only shows one message, last name which is weird because it's the 2nd one on the form.

Any idea how to output all the messages in the 'berichten' div?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replace HTML in `innerHTML`, use `+=` operator to add it:

```
function(errors, event) {
    /*cache DOM node*/
    var berichten = document.getElementById('berichten');

    /* #berichten content to replace*/
    var content = '';

    /*add errors to string variable */
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
            content += errors[i].message + '<br>';
        }

    }

    /* replace old content by new generated */
    berichten.innerHTML = content;
}
```